# SSRS - Deployin report to remote server

Tags: reporting-services

I'm trying to deploy an SSRS report to a remote server for my client. when i try :`http://serverIP/reportserver_dev/Pages/Folder.aspx?ItemPath=FolderName&ViewMode=List` url it again show me "username and password" screen without any error messages. And when i try `http://serverIP/reportserver_dev` url, it give url not find error. I tried a lot of time but couldn't find any way.

Comment: Are you sure it's installed? If you are typing http://serverIP/reportserver_dev into a browser and getting url not found then it doesn't appear to actually be installed

Comment: It is installed. And i can browse esxisting reports on ServerIP/ReportServer_DEV. May my user doesn't have publish access on that server?

Comment: You previously said in your question that you got a not found error at this URL.

Comment: I can open url by browser. But I get issue when publishing from Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

They are not standard urls for report server.

have you tried

http://serverIP/reportserver

or

http://serverIP/reports

Once you have a connection that actually goes somewhere, you can then troubleshoot further...

Comment: yes i tried but couldn't connect to standard URLs too.